# Как перебрать несколько селекторов сразу?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть несколько кнопок и аудио в DOM:

```
<audio class="aud" src="<?= $dir.$f ?>"></audio>
<button class="btn__play<? $sd = " btn__play".time();echo $sd; ?>">Play</button>
```

Сейчас их мало, но из-за PHP Обработчика их в DOM Много...
Так вот, и есть скрипт:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn__play, .aud').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      player.play();
    });
});
```

Проблема в чём... В том, что мне нужно как-то пройтись не только по кнопкам, но и по аудио... А вот как передавать несколько параметров, не известно...

Заранее, спасибо за Помощь!

Comment: Извините, заголовок вопроса немного не совпадает с описанием...

Comment: А почему бы просто не сделать всё это раздельно?

Comment: @ΝNL993, Раздельно? Как же это сделать-то...

Comment: Немного не понимаю что вы хотите, можно сделать проверку по классу, `if(item.className === 'aud') { /* если аудио делать что-то */ } if(item.className.indexOf('btn__play') != -1) { /* если кнопка плей делать что-то */ }`, вставьте код в колбеке (функции) которая в forEach

Comment: @ΝNL993, Спасибо. Сейчас буду пробовать!

Comment: @ΝNL993, Даже и не знаю...

Comment: Вот код, который мне удалось изобрести -document.querySelectorAll('.btn__play, .aud').forEach(item => {
  if(item.className === 'aud') {
    if(item.className.indexOf('btn__play') != -1) {
      this.addEventListener('click', (aud) => {
        aud.play();
      });
    }
  }
});

Comment: @ΝNL993, Но всё же, это не работает...(

Comment: Так вы неправильно сделали, у вас одна проверка в другой, а они по отдельности, это сделано для того чтобы для аудио сделать что-то одно, а для btn__play что-нибудь другое, если я конечно правильно понял вашу задачу. А так получается такая история: идёт проверка, является ли класс aud? -> есть ли в классах btn__play? -> сделать что-то, в итоге на проверках всё и останавливается и ничего не работает.

Comment: По нажатию на КНОПКУ происходит событие, и включается музыка. А кнопок несколько, и ссылок на разные треки несколько, поэтому не знаю что делать... Уже второй день мучаюсь, так и не могут помочь, уже на трех форумах лазил, и ничего так и не нашёл...(

Comment: Подозреваю что это из-за плохой формулировки, вот к примеру возьмём то что вы мне написали: `А кнопок несколько, и ссылок на разные треки несколько`, ну к примеру, есть треки и вот непонятно, толи вам нужно чтобы у несколько кнопок меняли треки, толи вы хотите чтобы было неопред. кол-во треков и на все чтобы были события (эвенты). Попробуйте подробно и всё конкретизируя написать вопрос.

Comment: @ΝNL993, Ну смотрите. Есть три кнопки, по нажатию на каждую играет разная музыка. Также имеется несколько audio тегов, в которых ссылки на треки, с помощью JS Скрипта мне нужно всё реализовать.

Comment: И всё объяснение которые вы написали, нужно писать не в комментариях, а в вопросе, комментарии  не предназначены для объяснения вопроса или публикации кода, вопрос можно отредактировать нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1431075/edit). А я сейчас попробую написать вам ответ.

Comment: Так, я посмотрел код, похоже, что у вас не [минимальный **воспроизводимый** пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), во-первых, я не знаю что за элемент такой `player`, во-вторых, если у вас есть плеер, тогда зачем проигрывать ещё одно аудио (я про элементы `aud`)? А там дальше спокойно меняете src у плеера и радуетесь жизни.